# Subsetting a data frame and running calculations in one pass

Tags: r

Trying to subset a dataframe and also do some basic calculations in one pass to avoid having to duplicate the function over and over. The subset part is selecting specific columns. And the basic calculations are simple comparisons between various columns.

Here's some data:

```
structure(list(name = structure(1:12, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"), class = "factor"), data_2018 = c(4, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3), 
data_2017 = c(1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
pilot = c(2.68421052631579, 2.73684210526316, 
3.52631578947368, 3.42105263157895, 3.05263157894737, 2.78947368421053, 
2.21052631578947, 3.68421052631579, 2.36842105263158, 3.73684210526316, 
2.47368421052632, 2.05263157894737), 
all = c(2.77777777777778, 
2.85185185185185, 3.62962962962963, 3.51851851851852, 3.18518518518519, 
2.92592592592593, 2.2962962962963, 3.74074074074074, 2.40740740740741, 
3.77777777777778, 2.55555555555556, 2.07407407407407), 
general = c(2.79166666666667, 
2.79166666666667, 3.58333333333333, 3.45833333333333, 3.08333333333333, 
2.83333333333333, 2.41666666666667, 3.70833333333333, 2.54166666666667, 
3.79166666666667, 2.54166666666667, 2.16666666666667), 
tool = c("DoS", 
"DoS", "DoS", "DoS", "DoS", "DoS", "DoS", "DoS", "DoS", "DoS", 
"DoS", "DoS"), status = c(6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 2, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here's what I've tried:

```
diffs <- select(agged
                , agged$data_2018
                , ifelse(agged$data_2018 >= agged$data_2017, 1, -1)
                , ifelse(agged$data_2018 >= agged$pilot, 1, -1)
                , ifelse(agged$data_2018 >= agged$all, 1, -1)
                , ifelse(agged$data_2018 >= agged$general, 1, -1))
```

But that's returning the

> Error Each argument must yield either positive or negative integers.

Hoping that expected output would be something like :

```
data_2018 | vs_data_2017 | vs_pilot | vs_all | vs_general
4         |    1         |    1     |   -1   |    1
4         |    1         |    1     |   -1   |    1
4         |    -1        |    1     |   1   |    1
4         |    -1        |    -1    |   1   |    1
3         |    1         |    -1    |   1   |    1
4         |    -1        |    1     |   1   |    -1
```

I've tried running just the `ifelse` part on its own and that returns a vector of correct integers, so I'm not sure what else to try. Is there a way to do this without even `dplyr`? Would love to be able to do this without that package.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: added, but it doesn't match the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood, this might be what you want :

```
cbind(data_2018 = agged$data_2018, sapply(c("data_2017", "pilot", "all", "general"), function(c) (agged$data_2018 >= agged[[c]]) * 2 - 1))
```

You apply condition on the columns you want to be -1 or 1 depending on condition. The boolean TRUE or FALSE is converted from 0/1 to -1/1 using *2-1.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice but seems to be returning a list or matrix. Is there a nicer way to have this return a dataframe instead of wrapping `as.data.frame()` around the entire line?

Comment: `data.frame(agged$data_2018, sapply(c("data_2017", "pilot", "all", "general"), function(c) (agged$data_2018 >= agged[[c]]) * 2 - 1))`

Comment: Got another question to add onto this function. If I wanted to add another column after all of data_2017, pilot, all, and general (so 4 more columns), is there a way to do that by adding onto the original function? So if `agged[[c]] > 0` then `agged[[c_color]] = "green" else "red"`

Comment: Something like this should do it : `data.frame(agged$data_2018, 
           sapply(c("data_2017", "pilot", "all", "general"), function(c) (agged$data_2018 >= agged[[c]]) * 2 - 1),
           col = c("red", "green")[as.numeric(agged$general > 3)+1])`

Answer (score 1):

```
require(dplyr)
agged %>% 
  mutate(vs_data_2017 =  if_else(data_2018 >= data_2017, 1, -1),
         vs_pilot     =  if_else(data_2018 >= pilot    , 1, -1),
         vs_all       =  if_else(data_2018 >= all      , 1, -1),
         vs_general   =  if_else(data_2018 >= general  , 1, -1)) %>%
  select(data_2018, vs_data_2017, vs_pilot, vs_all , vs_general)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution:

```
library(dplyr)

agged %>%
  select(data_2018, data_2017, pilot, all, general) %>%
  mutate_at(2:5, funs(if_else(data_2018 >= ., 1, -1))) %>%
  rename_at(2:5, funs(str_c('vs_', .)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you can directly use the comparison symbol (`>=`), i.e.

```
(dd$data_2018 >= dd[3:6]) * 1

#   data_2017 pilot all general
#1          1     1   1       1
#2          1     1   1       1
#3          1     1   1       1
#4          1     1   1       1
#5          1     0   0       0
#6          1     1   1       1
#7          0     0   0       0
#8          1     1   1       1
#9          1     1   1       1
#10         1     1   1       1
#11         1     1   1       1
#12         1     1   1       1
```

**NOTE:** I converted to 0 and 1 instead. You can easily change it to 1 and -1

Comment: I like this, but I'm getting an error related to the number of columns not matching. `length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`

Comment: Hmm...I m not sure as too why it would throw that error